# Ruby on Rails start additional script on server startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is a pretty basic question, I tried searching but the question is a little obscure for Google searches.

When I start my rails server I want it to additionally start a script I wrote that just gives a feed of different system resources (i.e. CPU usage, incoming & outgoing connections, as well as alerts if resources get to high, etc.) Preferably it starts in a separate terminal windows.

Additional information if it helps any:
OS: Kali Linux 
Ruby: 2.0.0
Rails: 4.0.3
WEBrick: 1.3.1

Answer (score 2):

What you are wanting is Rails Initializers ([guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files))

After rails starts up it then runs all the code in 'config/initializers'.

1. Under 'config/initializers' create a new file eg 'system_resources.rb'.
2. Initialize your code in there.

Comment: That works good except that when I try to navigate to my server in the browser it says the server cannot be found, but the server is running and so are the resources - no errors printed to the console @Evolve

Comment: Umm 1. Within your initializer try a good old `puts` statement and then see if you can see that in the logs outputting to your console. eg puts 'this should work'. 2. Checking basics, are you accessing the correct port eg. usually http://localhost:3000 3. Does the rails app load fine when you delete/comment out your initializer code?

Comment: This also runs on rails console or rake tasks that load the rails environment.